# Earliest historical example of "[super]heroes NEVER kill" and when did the prohibition become pervasive and accepted?

Tags: comics, history-of, behind-the-scenes, super-hero

Today, it's often taken for granted or as a truism that heroes don't kill (despite plenty of evidence historically [and in fiction](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/fans-uncover-deadly-truth-behind-marvel-cinematic-universe-1137189) to [the contrary](https://www.businessinsider.com/marvel-characters-that-have-killed-the-most-2015-5)).  In fact, it is often taken to the extreme that the heroic ideal ought *never* kill under *any* circumstance, situation, exception, or excuse - or otherwise [deny their right to *be* a hero](https://elfanboypodcast.podbean.com/e/fanboy-69-talking-superman-with-mark-waid-early-aquaman-buzz-and-marvels-dilemma/).  The [in-story rationales](https://www.polygon.com/2016/3/18/11256828/daredevil-netflix-season-2) are often paper-thin, unrealistic tautologies: "because we don't."

Several trace this to the mid-1950s, Fredric Wertham's attacks and congressional hearings and the subsequent Comics Code Authority, but Batman and Superman had already been reined in by Frederick Whitney Ellsworth, editorial director of DC, over a decade earlier.  [According to Slate](http://www.slate.com/articles/arts/culturebox/2015/04/batman_s_murderous_past_daredevil_s_moral_dilemma_why_superheroes_don_t.html), responding to parental censure and an editorial in the Chicago Daily News, Ellsworth told Batman writer Bill Finger that Batman should "never carry a gun again."

**What is the earliest example of a heroic figure with an absolute prohibition on killing?**

I am not speaking about situational mercy (like David refusing to cut down Saul) or a general view that unnecessary killing is bad and to be avoided.  Instead, the more extreme position that there are no situations where killing is permissible, moral, excusable, acceptable, allowable, justified, or tolerated *for* a hero (because this position is always outwardly hypocritical in that *others* may justifiably kill *sometimes* but *not* the hero; ex: Batman allowing Alfred to arm himself with a shotgun or working with police armed with sidearms).

The Lone Ranger comes to mind who, despite his trademark silver bullets, is said to fire his gun only to disarm, believing only the justice system can mete out a final disposition for lawbreakers.  Are there earlier examples of such absolutists?

I tend to believe these are outliers and exceptions to the rule, because it seems like the vast majority of pop culture endorses the occasional need for death.  And perhaps not-so-occasional when it comes to the Marvel Cinematic Universe with an [estimated body count](http://www.bodycounters.com/statistics.php) of 5,002,617 (Infinity War excluded for reasons).  Nonetheless, I still routinely hear the rationales raised even though it doesn't jibe with thousands of years of hero stories and even our present day heroic narratives.

**Is the absolute prohibition pervasive and, if so, when did it become accepted?**

When did "There's always another way." become a thing?

Not just an observation of what was happening but asserted as a value and truism in-story?

Comment: If I recall the reruns of '50s and '60s TV shows for kids, those heroes never killed. Like *The Lone Ranger* and the old George Reeves *Superman*. In the '80s there was another rash of that, like *The A-Team*, *MacGuyver*, *Charlie's Angels*, *Wonder Woman*, *The Six Million Dollar Man*, *The Incredible Hulk*, etc., etc. In *Airwolf* the hero would shoot down enemy helicopters only for the occupants to crawl from the flaming wreckages coughing and covered with soot, but alive. Which is why things like Frank Miller's *The Dark Knight* and Tim Burton's *Batman* seemed so edgy when they came out.

Comment: I think I'd distinguish "no one dies" from "never kill"... for example, the GI Joe cartoon exemplifies what you describe: vehicles exploding but people ALWAYS live.  But, I think there is- arguably- still lethal intent even if everyone HAPPENS to live, which is why it's a shock in the theatrical versions of GI Joe or Transformers when characters actually die.  The ideas are definitely connected though.  That kids shouldn't SEE death aligns with their heroes never killing.

Comment: Damn, this is a good question. I can’t wait for the answer!

Comment: Hrm...I thought it might be doc savage, but he killed on occasion. He tried to avoid it, but did when necessary.

Comment: FWIW, I think the reason to close this as off-topic is that it's not only a SFF trope. I'm voting to leave open since we've seen other "history-of" tropes like this one (not SFF-exclusive) with SFF answers.

Comment: Probably a good question for the Movies and TV site.

Comment: @DJClayworth - Probably better for literature.

Comment: Specific note on Batman: I have always assumed that his decision not to carry a gun had to do with the fact that a gun was used to kill his parents. Also, during a time when he was in a particularly bad mood, he chose not to free an opponent from a situation in which the opponent would die of thirst/starvation.

Comment: VtCers - per the tags, this is listed as being specific to super-hero comics. IF we accept that limitation, I think it's both on-topic, and may be answerable.

Comment: @RDFozz: I'm a bit concerned that "is it pervasive" is too vague and subjective to be meaningfully answered, but not VTCing because I think that can just be edited out.

Comment: Hmm. I wondered if the Comics Code Authority might have had some impact here. However, per the rules listed on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comics_Code_Authority), I don't see anything that would necessarily have prevented the likes of the Punisher from being published in the 1950s (as long as the "gunplay" was not "excessive", and they didn't depict him killing anyone in a "gory" or "gruesome" manor). Criminals may not have been allowed to kill law enforcement officials, but nothing says the reverse is true.

Comment: @ToddWilcox not for Airwolf. Plenty of things blown up with bad dudes inside (but without on-screen blood). Just look at the first episode: I don't think that Moffett fared very well after getting a missile in the face - which incidentally I always thought was unnecessarily heavy-handed from a hero, and I'm pretty sure Hawke didn't know he was in danger of being blown up himself.

Comment: WRT The Lone Ranger - silver bullets are expensive - you want to leave as few as possible behind in dead bodies.

Comment: The comic book writers keep this covered up, but over the years more people have died as a result of being punched by Batman than would have died from gunshot wounds inflicted by him if he'd carried a gun.

Comment: For an extreme example: https://youtu.be/IIPZROBiNik

Comment: Did the original Human Torch have any issues regarding killing?

Comment: @Gothamite24 No issues, definitely.  In Marvel Comics #1 (1939), the Human Torch CELEBRATES killing, "Help! The heat is killing me!" / "That rat burned down all right!" - That said, it makes an odd note that Sardo- the boss targeted that evening- dies by his own hand when he tries to throw a volatile chemical at Torch and the explosion ends up killing himself instead.  Seemed more just desserts than a matter of keeping Torch pure or heroic though, who's positively sadistic and happy to scald, maim, and kill with fire.